# チャットの意義について

Tags: 討議, サポート, チャット

あまり、チャットについての言及がメタやコメントにおいて、総じてなされてきていなくって、そもそもチャットがあることすら知らない人もある程度いるかもしれないと思いながら、個人的に考えるスタックオーバーフローにおけるチャットの立ち位置をまとめてみます。

スタックオーバーフローのシステムは、「質問」と「回答」を通じて、対象ドメイン(日本語版スタックオーバーフローは、プログラミング)に関する問題解決の知見を集約することに特化してデザインされています。質問と回答が第一級の投稿であり、究極的には、問題解決のための投稿以外は整理・淘汰・削除されていく設計です。

こういった設計は、コミュニティの目的である「問題の解決、知見の集約」に照らして考えてみると非常に合理的なのですが、なんというか、こう、「冷たいサイトだ」と感じられる（かもしれない）設計です。[メタサイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)も、こっちはこっちで「コミュニティの目的を追求するための意思決定・議論の場」としての機能面が強く、それ以外の「雑談」のような、その他コミュニケーションを行うにはあまり適していません。

こういった仕組み自体に対して何か問題があるわけではなく、「問題解決・知見集約」としての機構を回していくことは、コミュニティとしての第一目的です。ただ、「冷たいコミュニティであること」と「問題解決の機能的なコミュニティであること」は必ずセットの性質であるという訳でもないはずです。チャットは、そういったその他コミュニケーションを行うための場として用意されていると理解しています。

実際、機能的に特化して運営されているメインサイトでの質問・回答投稿や、メタサイトでの議論投稿などは、サイトに慣れてくれば問題ないのですが、割と独自の規律に従って回っている部分はあり、かつ「冷たい」設計になっているので、初心者やこれからサイトを使ってみようと思っているユーザーにとってはとっつきづらいかもしれません。

「スタックオーバーフローに興味・関心はあるけれども、なんか敷居高い」であるとか、「質問・回答以外の雑談してみたいんだけど」であるとか、「質問としてはクローズされるようなトピックなんだけれども、話してみたいな」であるとかの欲求があったときに、これを行える仕組みとして提供されているのが、スタックオーバーフローのチャットであると認識しています。

特に目的を求めない、汎用チャット部屋としては、ひとまず[チャット - 何でも部屋](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17893/) が用意されています。何かしら質問・回答以外の話をしたくなった場合は、ひとまずここに投稿するといいと思います。自分は最近チャットに頻繁に出没するようにしているので、何かあれば気軽に @メンションを飛ばしていただければと思います。

Comment: ここまで書いて、そういえばチャットに投稿するのってある程度信用度が必要だったな。。って思っています。ひとまず、大意は変わらないのでそのままにしておきます。